# Using $index in clicking on tag does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple example (see: http://plnkr.co/edit/w15Ov5T3vMXK7bfC34M2?p=preview])

I'm using the `ng-repeat` directive to display my data.

The data comes in 'groups'. Within each group I have *dynamic* data and *static* data.

I want to let the user be able to **toggle** the visibility of the dynamic data within each group.

In my html, I've set up, for each group, two buttons: one uses `onclick` the other `ng-click`.

On each button I also added a dummy attribute `data-private-index` with the value of `"{{$index}}"` to make sure Angular does the proper substitution.

This works. The substituted value appears in the DOM when I insepect the element in the browser.

There is a `div` that wraps each dynamic data. I set its `id` attribute to `"group-{{$index}}"` which is also seen to work (by inspecting the DOM element).

In each button I set up a *click* event handler with the idea of toggling the visibility of the `div` wrapping the dynamic data.

[image]

Some surprises I ran into:

1 - The value of `{{$index}}` does not appear to get substituted for in the `onclick` attribute (see by inspecting DOM)

Clicking on the first button triggers the `alert(...)`. But I get the message

> toggling group {{$index}}

which further demonstrates that substitution did not take place.

So why does substitution take place on the `div` but not on the `onclick` attribute? **What am I missing?**

2 - Clicking on the second button does not even trigger the `alert(...)`.

It appears that the `ng-click` is silently ignored (perhaps due to some error that I am unable to discern)

---

So, how can I dynamically toggle the visibility of the `div`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use use one variable that will be responsible for toggling div. You could do use `show` variable on each repeated div that will be maintained as toggle able flag.

**Markup**

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in ['group#0', 'group#1', 'group#2']">
    <p>{{item}}
      <button ng-click="alert('toggling group '+ $index); show=!show" data-private-index="{{$index}}">
        Toogle group #{{$index}} using ng-click
      </button>
    </p>

    <div id="group-{{$index}}" ng-show="show">
      ..content here..
    </div>

    <div>
      <br/> Static non-toggled data
      <br/> Static non-toggled data
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6xcibHasDclLO9U7myGa?p=preview)

You `onclick` event is not working because you are trying to call toggle method of the element `document.querySelector('group-{{$index}}')` which will not give the element because you can not access angular scope variable inside native javascript method like you are trying to access index using `{{}}` which will never gonna work. For such situation angular does provided his own method like `ng-click`, `ng-blur`, `ng-focus` etc are event based directives. Though you get accessed to element and used correct `id` of element eg. `document.querySelector('group-1')` you could not able make `.toggle` as workable, for that you need to add jQuery, then only you could use `.toggle()` on element.

While dealing with angular you should not suppose to use jQuery while playing with elements, because that could lead to binding updation problem, most of times you need to run digest cycle manually to update binding using `$scope.$apply()` but don't do this. Its considered as Bad practice in AngularJS. You could use `jQuery` but it should wrap in directive so that you could get control on Angular DOM and modified it in angular context.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently angular process the events statements of a very personal way, you must use the ng-click directive.

You can do something like this `id="'car_{{ $index }}'"` but it fail inside the events.

There is a few ways to hide an element, the most direct is the ng-hide and ng-show directives.

To use with a more specific behaviour you can use ng-class that allow you to put a especific class depending of a condition ng-class='{ 'my-custom-hide': areaVisible}'